# Recommended Clang command line options

Tags: c, clang, c89

The [Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) for Clang seems to be work in progress, so could you help me formulate the definitive command line options for compiling ANSI-C (AKA C89, C90) with maximum strictness and relevant/helpful warnings?

> Clang is a compiler front end for the
>   C, C++, and Objective-C programming
>   languages. It uses the Low Level
>   Virtual Machine (LLVM) as its back
>   end. It is still under development.
>   Its goal is to offer a replacement to
>   the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)

Comment: Maybe try changing to -arch PDP11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang's command-line arguments are, for the most part, GCC-compatible, so `-std=c90 -pedantic` should suffice.

Comment: I was told in the LLVM irc channel that there is no currently no complete listing for clang options so the general solution is in fact "man gcc"!